# /customer/section/load/?sections=cart 404 bad request magento 2

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

add to cart action not updating the minicart block in magento 2.
dev tool console returning following error.

> XHR GET /customer/section/load/? sections=cart&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=1569726426149
>   [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 2104ms]

This error are generating if amasty Cookie Consent (GDPR) module is active. 
Does any one have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Try to uninstall mod_security on server.

Answer (score 0):

Check error_Log on the server. If the error caused by **ModeSecurity** then find the ModSecurity Rule Id and add this in the **ModeSecurity** Disabled Rules.

You can do this by edit **ModSecurity** Configuration file and add

```
########################################
## Removed Rules for Magento 2
########################################
SecRuleRemoveById 981172
```

save the file and restart apache.